# Applying law of Biot-Savàrt when magnetic field passes through different materials

Tags: electromagnetism

Hi I'm trying to calculate the power of a magnetic field outside a coil winded around a electric steel core. The point I'm trying to measure is on the axis of the coil but 2 mm outside the electric steel core component. How do I go about doing the calculation?

The equation I was trying to use is this one:

$$B_x=\frac{\mu_0NI\pi a^2}{2\pi(x^2+a^2)^{\tfrac32}}$$

which is for when the coil doesnt have a core and we're only talking about air is my assumption.

If I instead want to use a different material do I swap out $\mu_0$ for the permeability of that material? What if the point I want to calculate the field density passes through both air and a different material between the point and the center of the coil?

I'm doing this as a calculation experiment in order to optimize an electric engine.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: In such cases, i.e. where the geometry is not simple, I would seek to use numerical solvers for magnetostatics: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Could_anyone_recommend_a_good_free_magnetostatics_software_package_I_am_looking_to_quantify_magnetic_forces_between_hard_magnets_and_ferromagnets

Comment: The Biot-Savart formula is the solution to Maxwell's equations in trivial geometry, free-space + some current-carrying wires. Once you have a material with non-trivial permeability, it becomes difficult and it is not at all clear to me that Biot-Savart is applicable.

Comment: Thank you very much! Im trying to solve my problem by simulating different drawings  in FEMM now instead.